# "Could not load file or assembly" when the referenced dll file is in the loaded assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection

The structure of my solution is as follows:

I got 2 projects. Independent of each other at compile time (no cross references). The second one is a class library that is loaded at runtime from the first one.

That library has its own dll dependencies, which I guess is what causes the exception thrown when I'm trying to do execute code using these dlls. I supposed that these referenced dlls are probably not loaded at runtime, except from the class library dll. Therefore, I added some code to load the referenced assemblies before executing any code of the loaded assembly.

To my surprise the "problematic" dll is already included in the loaded assemblies when the following code is executed, its location is correct, but the error still occurs and I have no idea how to further troubleshoot the issue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
try
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath(filename));

    //Try to find the type the derived plugin class
    foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
    {
        if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PluginBase)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plugin class detected! {0}", t.Name);


            //Get Referenced Assemblies
            AssemblyName[] l = a.GetReferencedAssemblies()                                     
            //Get Loaded Assemblies
            var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

            foreach (AssemblyName a2 in l)
            {
                var asm = loadedAssemblies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == a2.FullName);

                if (asm == null)
                {
                    Assembly test = null;
                    try
                    {
                        //First try to load using the assembly name just in case its a system dll    
                        test = Assembly.Load(a2);
                        //Try to load the assemly from the plugin directory
                        if (test == null)
                        {
                            test = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Join(a.Location, a2.Name + ".dll"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Callbacks.Log($"Unable to load assembly {a2.Name}", LogVerbosityLevel.WARNING);

                    }

                    if (test != null)
                    {
                        Callbacks.Log($"Loaded Assembly {a2.Name}", LogVerbosityLevel.WARNING);
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(test.GetName());
                    }

                }
            }


            object c = Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] { this });
            Plugins[Path.GetFileName(filename)] = c as PluginBase;
            //Call Dll initializers
            t.GetMethod("OnLoad").Invoke(c, new object[] { });
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log("Error during loading of plugin " + filename, LogVerbosityLevel.INFO);
    Log("Exception type " + ex.Data, LogVerbosityLevel.INFO);
}
```

Comment: Might be the wrong version of the assembly.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It wouldn't matter cause the referenced assembly is only required by the class library. I'm experimenting right now with the order that I load the references. I just tried to first load the class library dll first and then the references before invoking any code and it works! I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aight, I think I figured it out. So before the reason why I saw the referenced assemblies loaded was because I iteratively loaded them by browsing in a dll folder that contains the class library + its references. The main problem is that I am so stupid that I forgot to load them to the AppDomain calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyname)`. However when I did try to fix that I realized that trying to just fetch the related AssemblyName object does not work. I get the same FileNotFoundException.

What fixed the issue was to use `Assembly.LoadFrom` instead of `Assembly.LoadFile`. I read through the documentation that it states that `LoadFile` treats the loaded assemblies differently regardless if they are exactly the same dll file just in different location. In my case there is only a single path that I tried to load the assembly from, but I guess that `LoadFile` also differentiates the loaded assemblies in this case as well. However, I am still not sure why trying to use an AssemblyName coming from `LoadFile` crashes compared to what comes out of `LoadFrom`. I would expect that they would be identical...

I also added a failsafe mechanism to try and load only the desired dll files. I just expect that all dlls that will be loaded will be prepended with a text identifier. So at first the desired dll is loaded and before invoking any code, its references are loaded using the AssemblyName object or the actual path if the first fails.

Everything seems to be running nicely till now so hopefully this solves it.

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles("Plugins"))
    {
        if (!filename.EndsWith(("dll")))
            continue;
    
        if (!Path.GetFileName(filename).StartsWith(("Test")))
            continue;
    
        var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        //Load Assembly
        try
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.GetFullPath(filename));
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(a.GetName());
    
            //Try to find the type the derived plugin class
            foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
            {
                if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PluginBase)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Plugin class detected! {0}", t.Name);
    
                    //Load Referenced Assemblies
                    AssemblyName[] l = a.GetReferencedAssemblies();
                    loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    
                    foreach (AssemblyName a2 in l)
                    {
                        var asm = loadedAssemblies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == a2.FullName);
    
                        if (asm == null)
                        {
                            Assembly test = null;
                            try
                            {
                                //First try to load using the assembly name just in case its a system dll    
                                test = Assembly.Load(a2);
                            } 
                            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    Callbacks.Log($"Unable to load assembly {a2.Name}, Looking in plugin directory...", LogVerbosityLevel.WARNING);
                                    test = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Join(Path.GetDirectoryName(a.Location), a2.Name + ".dll"));
                                } catch (Exception ex2)
                                {
                                    Callbacks.Log($"Unable to load assembly {a2.Name}, Error: {ex2.Message}", LogVerbosityLevel.WARNING);
                                }
                            }
    
                            if (test != null)
                            {
                                Callbacks.Log($"Loaded Assembly {a2.Name}", LogVerbosityLevel.WARNING);
                                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(test.GetName());
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
    
    
                    object c = Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[] { this });
                    Plugins[Path.GetFileName(filename)] = c as PluginBase;
                    //Call Dll initializers
                    t.GetMethod("OnLoad").Invoke(c, new object[] { });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("Error during loading of plugin " + filename, LogVerbosityLevel.INFO);
            Log("Exception type " + ex.Data, LogVerbosityLevel.INFO);
        }
    
    }
```